# Android Java Objects

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to figure out, how to get to my Objects in object list.

I have made "MainHolder.class" where I made my Object list with simple variables(Later I want to add there boolean, real, integer and string values, so simple int array list wont work for me).

My Idea is about simple getting to my object. For example:

Displaying values like: `CarMain.PlayerLevel.name();`

Adding values like: `CarMain.PlayerLevel.count +=1;`

But now I got problem trying to Adding values.
Got error : `Cannot resolve symbol PlayerLevel`

In Line `CarMain.PlayerLevel.count +=1;`

This is my **MainHolder.class**

```
package com.crelix.crelix;

public class MainHolder {

int id;
String name;
int count;

public void id(int id) {
}

public MainHolder(String name) {

}

public void count(int count){
    this.count += count;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    MainHolder Money = new MainHolder("Money: ");
    MainHolder MoneyClicks = new MainHolder("Money Clicks: ");
    MainHolder Boxes = new MainHolder("Boxes: ");
    MainHolder BoxClicks = new MainHolder("Boxes Clicks: ");
    MainHolder BoxLevel = new MainHolder("Box Level: ");
    MainHolder PlayerLevel = new MainHolder("Player Level: ");
    MainHolder GarageLevel = new MainHolder("Garage Level: ");
    MainHolder GarageSlots = new MainHolder("Garage Slots: ");

    Money.id(1);
    Money.count(0);

    MoneyClicks.id(2);
    MoneyClicks.count(0);

    Boxes.id(3);
    Boxes.count(0);

    BoxClicks.id(4);
    BoxClicks.count(0);

    BoxLevel.id(5);
    BoxLevel.count(1);

    PlayerLevel.id(6);
    PlayerLevel.count(1);

    GarageLevel.id(7);
    GarageLevel.count(1);

    GarageSlots.id(8);
    GarageSlots.count(25);
}
```

}

And In **MainActivity** I want to add Player Level Like here:

```
public void upgradeLevel(View view){

for (int i =9; i >=0; i--){
    if (CarMain.PlayerLevel.count() == i){
        if (CarMain.Money.count() >= 100*i){
            CarMain.Money.count() = CarMain.Money.count() - (100*i);
            CarMain.PlayerLevel.count() += 1;
        }
    else{
          //Else
        }
   }
}
if (CarMain.PlayerLevel.count() == 10){
    //Max Level
}
```

}

Heres My Error in Image : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enSBr.png)

Comment: I don't see the `CarMain` class defined anywhere.

Comment: MainHolder CarMain = new MainHolder(); //Here I got. Just didn't write in topic. But now I saw, that theres error in that line to.. becouse of string. I just had array list before and now I'm trying all my classes like MainHolder. And got this problem.

Comment: It's very bad practice to start variables with a Capital letter, generally variables start with lower case and type names with upper case. Respecting convention will help avoid lots of confusion.

Comment: @AdelKhial CarMain is MainHolder.class definition.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `PlayerLevel` inside the main method of MainHolder. So it isn't visible to calling classes (in this case `MainActivity`). To access them you need to define them as global variables at the top which is a *very* bad thing to do. Also, you shouldn't declare `PlayerLevel` inside `MainHolder` in the first place since all you want that class to do is hold the id and count. Instead declare `PlayerLevel` inside MainActivity.

If you absolutely want a super class holding all your MainHolders you should use nested classes.